# Swift 5 make a view fill the rest of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

so I'm making a sort of calendar app for iOS, using FSCalendar. Anyways, I wanted to display the tasks / event of that day above the calendar itself. The constraints set for the UIView of the calendar are:

```
height = 300
Safe Area.bottom = Calendar.bottom
Calendar.trailing = Safe Area.trailing
Calendar.leading = Safe Area.leading
```

[(See the picture for a clear idea of the constraints / position.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKQsR.png) So what I'm trying to achieve is that I want to make the blue area relative to the area which isn't optimised yet. When I try to set the constraints to be 0 from top and the sides, I don't know how to make the blue square to be a certain size without pushing the calendar away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the height constraint of the blue area equal to the height of the superview minus the height of the calendar height. You can do this in storyboard or in code.

Disregard where it says Table View.Height. That would be your blue area height and 320 the height of your calendar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I fixed it by simply adding a vertical stack view, setting all those constraints to 0 and setting the height for the calendar.